# updating data from php function using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have two division in my file say **form.php**....

**Division A**

All data from table **abc** (here i am getting data from db)

---

**Division B**

Some fields

**Add Data (Button)** will store data in table **abc** through ajax using following code (It's storing data)

---

Now my problem is when i add data in **Division B** i want to update **Division A** with newly added data through ajax...

for that i am trying this code but i am getting console error say **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

```
  $("#addField").click(function(){ 
        label=$("#ilabel").val();
        name=$("#iname").val();
        type=$("#itype").val();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php', // this is adding **division B** data in database
            data : {reqtype:'insert',label:label,name:name,type:type},
            type: 'POST',
            success : function(data){ 
                $("#showform").html('<?php echo $d->fetchform() ?>'); // here i am trying to update Division A on success but getting error
            }
        })
    })
```

**$d->fetchform()** is giving all the formatted data from the table **abc**...

i don't know how to deal with this problem.. can you please suggest me how can i do it... (i want to do it through ajax only)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: use `$("parent-of-the-addfield-which-is-not-updating-with-ajax").on("click","#addfield",function(){ $("#showform").html('<?php echo $d->fetchform() ?>');});`  :May be this will work

Comment: you forget `var`... like var label... var name... etc

Comment: @aldanux there is not problem it's working fine... problem is <?php $d->fetchform() ?> line

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to output server-side code (i.e. the PHP echo code) via client-side. This will never work (you'll just end up outputting the whole string inside the html() call as-is, without getting it parsed).

You should try putting the php `fetchForm()` call in a web service, or another file on your server, and get the contents of that via AJAX again.